# Set type of variable dynamically based on passed interface{} type

Tags: go, interface

I am trying to effectively use bindings auto-generated by go-ethereum, which I stored in the uniswap_core package.
It created many different Event structs and each also has it's own Iterator struct.

Here is an example of code the tool *abigen* generated for an Iterator struct:

```
// IUniswapV3FactoryPoolCreatedIterator is returned from FilterPoolCreated and is used to iterate over the raw logs and unpacked data for PoolCreated events raised by the IUniswapV3Factory contract.
type IUniswapV3FactoryPoolCreatedIterator struct {
    Event *IUniswapV3FactoryPoolCreated // Event containing the contract specifics and raw log

    contract *bind.BoundContract // Generic contract to use for unpacking event data
    event    string              // Event name to use for unpacking event data

    logs chan types.Log        // Log channel receiving the found contract events
    sub  ethereum.Subscription // Subscription for errors, completion and termination
    done bool                  // Whether the subscription completed delivering logs
    fail error                 // Occurred error to stop iteration
}

// Next advances the iterator to the subsequent event, returning whether there
// are any more events found. In case of a retrieval or parsing error, false is
// returned and Error() can be queried for the exact failure.
func (it *IUniswapV3FactoryPoolCreatedIterator) Next() bool {
    // If the iterator failed, stop iterating
    if it.fail != nil {
        return false
    }
    // If the iterator completed, deliver directly whatever's available
    if it.done {
        select {
        case log := <-it.logs:
            it.Event = new(IUniswapV3FactoryPoolCreated)
            if err := it.contract.UnpackLog(it.Event, it.event, log); err != nil {
                it.fail = err
                return false
            }
            it.Event.Raw = log
            return true

        default:
            return false
        }
    }
    // Iterator still in progress, wait for either a data or an error event
    select {
    case log := <-it.logs:
        it.Event = new(IUniswapV3FactoryPoolCreated)
        if err := it.contract.UnpackLog(it.Event, it.event, log); err != nil {
            it.fail = err
            return false
        }
        it.Event.Raw = log
        return true

    case err := <-it.sub.Err():
        it.done = true
        it.fail = err
        return it.Next()
    }
}

// Error returns any retrieval or parsing error occurred during filtering.
func (it *IUniswapV3FactoryPoolCreatedIterator) Error() error {
    return it.fail
}

// Close terminates the iteration process, releasing any pending underlying
// resources.
func (it *IUniswapV3FactoryPoolCreatedIterator) Close() error {
    it.sub.Unsubscribe()
    return nil
}
```

I want to create a general function that, given any EventIterator and an interface{} channel, will iterate though the events and send them back via the channel.

A solution I've come up with is simply creating a type switch statement to get the appropriate Iterator type. But then I have to repeat the exact same iteration code within each **case** block.

How do I avoid this repetition?

```
func (f *contract_factory) readEvent(it interface{}, c_event chan interface{}) {
    //TODO figure how to avoid duplicating this shit
    switch iter := it.(type){
        case *uniswap_core.UniswapV3FactoryPoolCreatedIterator:
            for {
                if ! iter.Next() {
                    close(c_event)
                    if err := iter.Error(); err != nil {
                        f.logger.Error("failure while iterating events", zap.Error(err))
                    }
                    break
                }

                c_event <- iter.Event
            }
            iter.Close()

        case *uniswap_core.UniswapV3FactoryOwnerChangedIterator:
            for {
                if ! iter.Next() {
                    close(c_event)
                    if err := iter.Error(); err != nil {
                        f.logger.Error("failure while iterating events", zap.Error(err))
                    }
                    break
                }

                c_event <- iter.Event
            }
            iter.Close()

        default:
            err = errors.New("unknown event iterator type")
            f.logger.Error("unknown event iterator type", zap.String("iterator type", reflect.TypeOf(iter).String()))
            close(c_event)
    }
}
```

Comment: What packages are you using? What is `uniswap_core`? If it's generated, please provide the relevant generated code.

Comment: You may capture the `Next()` and `Error()` methods with an interface, and type-assert into this interface type. Accessing the `Event` field cannot be generalized, either use 2 variables or use reflection to access it.

Comment: Hum okay, I will try that out, thanks.

Comment: Would you show how to use reclection to access it?

Comment: @sotokin `e := reflect.ValueOf(iter).Elem().Field("Event").Interface()` produces a variable `e` of type `interface{}` with the underlying value being of the iterator-specific event type.

Comment: @mkopriva it actually had to be .Field(0) but it works, thanks a bunch!

Comment: @sotokin my bad, i meant `.FieldByName("Event")`. See [doc](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.FieldByName).